# SQL Server - Plan cache cleared very often

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-execution-plan

There are some performance issues on our SQL server. When we began to analyze, we found several problems, including that the plan cache is cleaned very often  for no reason (5-10 times per hour).

We also used the "sp_BlitzFirst" script for analysis and it also showed that we have problem: "Plan Cache Erased Recently".
However, we do not have any jobs that can perform cleaning. And no one performs cleaning manually, too.

We would like to know what might be the reasons for this behavior?

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

Total RAM: 32GB
SQL Server RAM: 29GB
Average RPS (requests per second): ~250
```

Comment: Maybe you should profile it and filter with events that have to following command in it: DBCC FREEPROCCACHE. Or maybe you have a failover cluster thats failing over? Or your service is restarted?

Comment: Already checked for "DBCC FREEPROCCACHE". This statement is not executed when cache clearing. We have only mirroring, but cluster never failing over. SQL Server last restart is "2017-03-05 00:11:25" (3rd May)

Comment: What is your full @@VERSION? (I cannot understand your v11.0.2100.60, it should be 10.0.smth as the question is tagged sql-server-2008)

Comment: You need to profile plan creation event in sql profiler.

Comment: @sepupic, tag fixed, thank you.

Comment: @VijayRaheja, sorry, but I can't find this event in sql profiler.

Comment: 1) Your plans could be purged out under memory pressure. 2)I recommend you to patch your server (to SP3) since you are still on RTM

Comment: 3) can you check if these 2 queries give you the same number? `select sum(cntr_value)
from sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
where counter_name IN ('Free Memory (KB)', 'Database Cache Memory (KB)', 'Stolen Server Memory (KB)');

select cntr_value
from sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
where counter_name = 'Total Server Memory (KB)';`

Comment: @sepupic:
1) How we can understand that our SQL Server needs more memory? It always use 29GB(which is limitation in settings)
2) If this is the last option, then we will do it. Because our system works 24/7, we can't allow downtimes
3) Both queries returns 29690648

Comment: Use this query `select counter_name, cntr_value from sys.dm_os_performance_counters
where object_name LIKE '%Manager%'
and counter_name = 'Page life expectancy'` to find out your PLE, it shows how much time data page stays in memory, low value means that you need more memory

Comment: Memory management was rewritten in 2012 and many bugs were fixed in successive SPs, so if you hit one of these bugs you resolve it by applying SP3